# How to: animate a MVVM ViewModel property in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I'd like to ask how, if possible, do you animate a property on a MVVM viewmodel in Silverlight. For example, here I have a typical Storyboard declaration in XAML:

```
  <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="yearSlider"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                    From="1990" To="2012" Duration="0:0:8" />
```

Now suppose instead of animating the Value property on Slider yearSlider, I want to instead animate the CLR (non-dependency) property "Year" on my MVVM viewmodel. For example, if my viewmodel is set to the DataContext, the code might hypothetically look as follows:

```
  <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.BindingSource="{Binding}"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Year"
                    From="1990" To="2012" Duration="0:0:8" />
```

Of course there is no such "BindingSource" property on Storyboard, but this should help illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Is there any mechanism in Silverlight 4 to accomplish this task of animating a MVVM viewmodel property, without resorting to adding code in the code-behind?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can do this.

The property in your MVVM must be a dependency property, not a normal property. Therefore, your MVVM must inherit from DependencyObject and then you can create a dependency property that can be animated.

```
public class MyViewModel : DependencyObject
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty YearProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Year", typeof(int),
    typeof(MyViewModel), null
    );

  public int Year
  {
    get { return (int)GetValue(YearProperty); }
    set { SetValue(YearProperty, value); }
  }
}
```

And then your XAML would look like this:

```
<DoubleAnimation
   Storyboard.Target="{Binding}"
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Year"
   From="1990" To="2012" Duration="0:0:8" />
```

Try that and let me know if it works.

If not, try fiddling around with it until you figure out how to satisfy the binding with the DoubleAnimation. Maybe you can piggy-back off of another element within scope:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="YearLabel" Text="{Binding Year}" />
<DoubleAnimation
   Storyboard.TargetName="YearLabel"
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="DataContext.Year"
   From="1990" To="2012" Duration="0:0:8" />
```

Notice how we are modifying the "DataContext.Year". It doesn't have to be a TextBlock. Can be any element with a name... like the RootLayout Grid for example.

Comment: could you show how the XAML would look, i.e. show the DoubleAnimation declaration?

Comment: When I set the property Target, I get the following error: Error 1 The property 'Target' does not exist on the type 'DoubleAnimation' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

Comment: Added another way to bind. The animation could be extra sensitive, so you may have to try different techniques to get to the actual view model.

Comment: Thanks for the info Laith. I appreciate your attempt so I've upvoted your answer. Unfortunately, I'm looking for an elegant solution that does exactly as specified, not fiddling around or hacks which involve binding to additional UIElements just to make this work.